# Изменение элемента строки по индексу

Tags: c++, строки

У меня есть такая задача: Есть слово, надо образовать из него все возможные слова, отличающиеся от него на одну букву. То есть пробежаться по каждому символу строки и изменить по очерёдно его на буквы из алфавита. Я Вопрос в следующем, я могу как-нибудь из исходной строки получить строку с изменённым по определённому индексу символом. Желательно, чтобы способ был наиболее быстрым.

Comment: Если массив char - вообще без проблем. По индексу меняйте почти на что хотите

Comment: Если `string` - "вообще без проблем. По индексу меняйте почти на что хотите" :)

Comment: @Harry, блин, прикольно, просто мой основной язык - Python. И там строки - неизменяемые объекты. Думал в плюсах также.

Comment: Строковые литералы - да, неизменяемые.